# Where to store object with String properties?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

Need some help with data storing, or just keeping. What to use?
I was thinking about Firebase, but not sure if this is the best and easiest way.

So it will be related with ML, and from ML, I will get a string, let's say `Rose` (this is going to be around 100-150 objects). This object, for now should keep a `description` which will be string value (~100-150 words), `name` - String value and `imageUrl` which should be a string as well. Later I will probably update, and add more.
So later, when I look for keyword `Rose` I would need to get `name` `description` and `imageUrl` for now.

So what is the best and easiest way to choose? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use Codable and write your data (json files) inside Application Support Directory

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If it is a lot of data, you should start with Firebase. The pitfalls with this is scalability if you plan to expand your app. Your other option is Core Data but the pitfall with this is your app build getting large depending how much information you need to store.

Comment: This is going to be ~100-150 objects with properties.

Comment: You should check how much data you can upload and download from the free Firebase account. If the cost exceeds your expectation, you may want to consider Core Data. Core Data as of today is much easier to implement than a couple of years ago. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: How is scalability a pitfall of Firebase - that's actually it's strong suit, being [massively scaleable](https://firebase.google.com/products-build). Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Good point @Jay. I meant to say that the "scaling" issue would be the cost if their app were to garner many users. In terms of the vast amount of data they want to save, using a backend would be a "scalable" solution.

Comment: @Jay I guess "cost" is something you can't avoid if you use Firebase or create your own custom backend.

Comment: @JustinK Well, based on the somewhat vague question, it seems like a tiny amount of data which would fall into the free plan for either Firestore or the RTDB. Even scaling up to a couple hundred users would probably be free. Thanks for clarifying the comment and I agree that starting with Firebase may be a good idea.

Comment: My pleasure @Jay. Be well.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is good if you need to access these strings over multiple devices. But if you're looking to just persist it on the same device, it's better to use Realm or CoreData or simply use UserDefaults.

Realm (if you have or at least know about Cocoapods):
https://cocoapods.org/pods/Realm#realm-swift

CoreData (Much more robust & faster to load, but more complicated to implement):
https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

UserDefaults (simpler to implement, but could take longer to load with the amount of data you might want to store):
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults

Comment: `UserDefaults` is used to save setting options to remember if a button was toggled or a screen has a different color setting.